# Cognito login works fine but getting 400 error in browser

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

strange one this, I am using angular 7 and using API gateway with authentication.

My problem is that on both using amplify and amazon-cognito-identity-js I get a 400 error in the browser.  All works fine but the error persists.

See below:-

```
Auth.configure({
      mandatorySignIn: false,
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:ssssssssssss',
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'eu-west-1', 
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'eu-west-1_ssssssssssss', 
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'sssssssss',
     })
    const user = Auth.signIn(userName, password).then(res =>
      {});
```

In the browser I get :-

POST https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 error

However, the code works, any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong app client ID.  Thanks for anyone who was looking

Comment: I also came across this. It worked but got a 400 in the console! In my case, it was because I didn't have my user pool added as an authentication provider for my identity pool. My app was using the unauthenticated role. I added my user pool and made sure the authenticated role had proper permissions.

This blog provides additional context:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-existing-cognito-resources-for-your-amplify-api-storage-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to activate guest access in my identity pool (using AWS console). This solved the 400 problem.